# Application changes are not reflecting after deployment in Wildfly 8.2 App Server

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

We are using Wildfly 8.2.0 Server and sometimes the hot deployment doesn't work, it says EAR/WAR module has been deployed  but changes are not reflecting until we restart our Application Server. Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue and how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "hot deployment"? From an IDE or are you editing files in an exploded deployment?

Comment: Hi James, by hot deployment what we meant is, we deployed the latest EAR file through wildfly-maven-plugin  using wildfly:deploy-only goal. We deploy packaged EAR file.

Comment: Hmm... ..that should definitely make the changes visible as it's going through a full redeployment. Are you sure it's not some kind of browser cache issue? I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: Yes, it's not a browser issue, we are exposing REST Services and we could see the logs getting printed in our servers whenever we submit a request (using CURL or client code), so definitely the requests are reaching the servers.